Do black holes convert 100% of their mass into energy via Hawking radiation?
And if so, does that mean that we do not need matter/antimatter annihilations for 100% mass to energy?

As far as we know, they completely decay. But a small percentage of the particles they decay into will be massive.

The Hawking radiation is a hypothesis based on forcing together two incompatible theories, classical and quantum. This radiation: (1) has not been predicted by a confirmed theory; (2) has not been observed experimentally; (3) violates major laws of physics, as expressed by the Information Paradox and Page Time Paradox. Thus, as far as proper science is concerned, the Hawking radiation does not exist, but likely is an unphysical artifact of two incompatible theories used together. Therefore black holes do not evaporate, no matter how many bored physicists confuse wishful thinking for science.

@safesphere the theory is not there, but this does not imply that real black holes do not evaporate. We just don't know.

@JánLalinský Well, we equally don’t know if real black holes emanate magical unicorns.

@safesphere Indeed, we don't know. So don't make statements they don't do it. It's unprovable.

Over the course of their lifespans, theoretically yes. As far as I know, we have never observed Hawking radiation from an actual macroscopic black hole (on account of the fact that we've never been to one), so it's still theory but it's a good theory at the very least with a significant amount of backing from the scientific community so far.
You would probably encounter several issues with replacing an antimatter with a black hole reactor:

You can't build a black hole reactor because doing so requires compressing astronomical amounts of mass into an extremely small radius (a 1-nanometer black hole would have a mass of about $6.733\cdot10^{17}$ kilograms, which is many orders of magnitude more than the total amount of mass ever mined by humanity). Antimatter might be hard to get, but it's easier to wait for $\beta^+$-decay to produce some positrons than to compress hundreds of even thousands of asteroids into a quantum-scale space.

A black hole reactor probably wouldn't work because black holes evaporate too slowly. The evaporation time for a black hole of mass $M$ is given by $$\frac{5120\pi G^2M^3}{\hbar c^4}$$ which is the cube of the mass multiplied by an extremely large value. For our already-impossible nanometer-sized black hole, it would evaporate over the course of around $2.567\cdot10^{37}$ seconds (around eight hundred octillion years), which would produce an average power output of around 2.3 milliwatts (in reality, it would be virtually zero power up until right before the black hole evaporates, at which point most of the energy would be released in a brief burst more powerful than any conceivable weapon). You could make the black hole lighter to increase power output, but lighter black holes are smaller, and that makes building it exponentially more difficult.

A black hole reactor would suffer a "meltdown" if not constantly fed. Assuming you could somehow stuff a million tons or so of matter into a space much smaller than quark charge radii at around one-and-a-half zeptometers, and continuously fed it a few tons of matter per second to keep it from evaporating completely, you could generate more than a zetawatt of power, way more than enough to launch an asteroidal city-spaceship into interstellar space even at extremely-low efficiency. The issue is, such a black hole would evaporate in a matter of minutes as soon as it's no longer being fed, whether you want it to or not. Antimatter reactors can be shut down - just turn off the antimatter/matter feeds - but with a black hole reactor, turning it off involves allowing the black hole to fully evaporate, not only destroying the reactor itself, but also everything around it in a miniature supernova.

Black hole reactors can't be effectively moved. You could have one that generates "just" a few terawatts of power and evaporates very slowly (i.e. measured in millions of years), but it would weigh billions of tons and would still be prohibitively small. On the surface of a planet, that would perturb the orbits of satellites and significantly alter spacetime near the reactor; in space, you wouldn't be able to push it around. A 1-million-ton black hole would be a few attometers across and would generate significant power, burning up after around 2,600 years, but it also weighs, well, a million tons, and can't be effectively moved from its point of creation. Plus, again, you can't turn it off - sucks to be whoever's on the planet in two-and-a-half thousand years.


If it's not clear, antimatter reactors do not suffer any of these flaws. Antimatter is very hard to get to, but it is easier to work with and easier to get to than black holes.

How to move a small black hole? If you attach a rocket motor, the motor would be sucked in. You might put a large mass next to the black hole and attach rocket motor to that. The large mass would attract the black hole. You would use the rocket motors to keep ahead. It would be a delicate balance keeping them exactly the right distance apart. You would need the gravitational acceleration of the black hole to exactly match the acceleration the rockets give to of the large mass. And now you are accelerating two large masses.

You could do the same thing with smaller mass by adding a charge to the black hole, and the opposite charge to the mass.

These things are both true! Still, you're trying to move an object that literally weighs as much as a mountain. Certainly heavier than any vehicle built to date.

Agreed. Nice answer!

Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_starship

"so you're saying there's a chance" :-D

In short: A useful BH is unfeedable (too tiny to hit with baryonic matter), and a feedable BH is useless (too little power output to work as a reactor). And if you ever come across a useful BH, better leave it alone, get back to your spaceship, and leave the system for good. You don't want to be around when the inevitable happens.

If you could somehow make a black hole from a reasonable amount of matter on demand, it would effectively instantly evaporate. The total energy released is then limited by what you put in, and you could just repeat the process at whatever rate necessary to achieve the net power output you desire. Such a black hole reactor wouldn't actually contain a black hole except for vanishingly short periods of time. Of course, we have no idea how this might actually be done. Further, if we could, I bet we'd have figured out more direct ways to achieve matter-energy conversion by that time.

This seems like the kind of thing that certainly requires physics beyond the standard model and beyond GR to make practical.

My instinctive - entirely layman - reaction to the question was "I don't think so, at some point enough of the black hole's mass will be evaporated to make it stop being a black hole" - could you educate me in why that is apparently wrong? Is the mass inside a black hole so compressed, or changed in its nature, that even if you reduce it (through hawking radiation) down to two protons' worth it would still have the characteristics of a black hole, and not be a helium (or two hydrogen) atom/ion?

A true black hole’s mass is “stored” in a zero-dimensional singularity at the center. If you include quantum-mechanical effects, there are some theories that suggest that below a limit of around 22 micrograms quantum gravitational effects would cause instant collapse into radiant energy but of course that’s not confirmed. Disregarding that, you can have a black hole of any size, regardless of mass - there have been good thought experiments dedicated to “what if a black hole had the same mass/charge/etc as an electron? Would it simply be an electron?” Short answer: we’re not sure. @Syndic

It would be far more efficient and feasible, if you had access to a black hole, to convert infalling matter into radiant energy via the accretion disk and/or a Penrose Process.
For the best case of a black hole rotating at near maximum possible rate, you could convert nearly 50% of an infalling object's rest mass into radiated energy.

Certainly, the total energy of the system has to remain the same, so all the mass of the black hole has to be converted into something that has an energy equivalent. So I think this question really boils down to whether Hawking radiation can contain particles like electrons or protons that have mass. And there are theoretical arguments that it can. If you google "can Hawking radiation produce baryons", you will find articles like this one proposing baryogenesis from Hawking radiation under certain circumstances. If this is correct, then some of the mass energy of those black holes will end up as matter, not (some other form of) energy.
I am not sure if scientists are confident of this one way or the other, but I would say the best way to learn more about it is to think of it in terms of what kinds of particles can be generated, rather than just thinking of the output as "energy".

FWIW, a BH has to be pretty small to emit electron + positron pairs, ~40 billion metric tons. See https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator and use 1022 keV for the peak photon energy.

True, so you could keep feeding matter in and getting energy out without a single massive particle. But if you're talking about 100% of the mass then it will get that small eventually. Still, +1 to controlgroup for a superior answer that really gets at what I think the asker wanted to know.

@MarkFoskey Ah and as mentioned elsewhere, trying to hit the BH small enough to not emit matter is hard enough it may only be feasible using something like high energy photons, making it useless for matter to energy conversion.

The answer to this question is somewhat subjective, but I would argue that it's still an open question. I don't think that we have any good enough theories of quantum gravity to say with any kind of confidence how a black hole behaves once it gets down to around the Planck mass.
